# Why does Abel Nightroad's hair stick up?

Tags: trinity-blood

In Trinity Blood, Abel Nightroad's hair sticks up when he is in vampire form. Is there any reason given either in-canon or by one of the creators?

Comment: Because when people change forms it's popular to give them spiky hair. Ala DBZ.

Comment: No in-canon reason given, but apparently it should have something to do with the nanomachines activation. You should check the original Sunao Yoshida's novels to say if it's something that appears only in the anime for a stylistic reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have read the Sunao Yoshida's novels and there is no information regarding why he gets the spiky hair. Looking in the internet I have found no interviews of Sunao Yoshida talking about it, so the only thing I can say it is just something stylish to the electric discharges he is able to do when he transforms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like everyone mentioned above. This is more of a visual effect to give the viewer the sense of change in the character during that specific sequence. =)